# How to get yahoo mails in to Android app programmatically

Tags: android

I want to show all yahoomail mails in my android app. Using Imap is it possible?
Does Imap supports yahoomail?

Following is the code I tried.

following is the code to get yahoomails

```
public void getYahooMails(View V) throws MessagingException {

    try {

        store = imapSession.getStore("imaps");

        store.connect("imap.mail.yahoo.com", "username", "password");
        System.out.println("*******Message here********"
                + store.isConnected());
        if (store.isConnected()) {
            inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message[] result = inbox.getMessages();
            System.out.println(result.length + "======"
                    + inbox.getUnreadMessageCount());

            /*
             * for(int i=result.length;i>0;i--) { if(i==1000) {
             * System.out.println
             * (result[i].getSubject()+"=====mesaage ====>"
             * +result[i].getSentDate()); } }
             */

        }
    } catch (Exception w) {

        // w.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("*******Message here********"
                + store.isConnected());
        // System.out.println(w.getMessage());
        w.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use the [sourcecode of android k9 mail](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9) as an example.

I am using k9 to read my yahoo mails using **pop3 protocol**. I donot know if you can access yahoo via imap.